# 'Background' property is not valid for text formatting

Tags: wpf, richtextbox

I'm using the standard WPF `RichTextBox` control.

I can set the foreground color successfully, but setting the background color gives the follow error:

> System.ArgumentException: ''Background' property is not valid for text formatting.'

Here is the code I'm testing with:

```
// SUCCESS
this.rtfDocument.Selection.ApplyPropertyValue(
    System.Windows.Controls.RichTextBox.ForegroundProperty,
    System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Red);

// ERROR
this.rtfDocument.Selection.ApplyPropertyValue(
    System.Windows.Controls.RichTextBox.BackgroundProperty,
    System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Blue);
```

I am using the `System.Windows.Media` namespace brushes as other Stackoverflow questions mention.

**EDIT:**

Interestingly, even *getting* the background color throws this error:

```
// SUCCESS
var f = this.rtfDocument.Selection.GetPropertyValue(
    System.Windows.Controls.RichTextBox.ForegroundProperty);

// ERROR
var b = this.rtfDocument.Selection.GetPropertyValue(
    System.Windows.Controls.RichTextBox.BackgroundProperty);
```

Perhaps the error is to do with the actual property itself somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `TextRange.ApplyPropertyValue` method applies property values to document elements, not to the RichTextBox itself.

So don't set RichTextBox properties, but TextElement properties instead:

```
rtfDocument.Selection.ApplyPropertyValue(
    System.Windows.Documents.TextElement.ForegroundProperty,
    System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Red);

rtfDocument.Selection.ApplyPropertyValue(
    System.Windows.Documents.TextElement.BackgroundProperty,
    System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Blue);
```